# Form shifts to the left after making selections

Tags: html, css

On mobile (or desktop with small window size to replicate mobile, as per the screenshots) the form on my page loads fine with default dates, but when a new date range is selected the form shifts to the left after making the selection (or rather, a gap is inserted to the right) but I can't find anything using F12 developer tools that is causing it. It is not possible to scroll to the left.

On page load:

[image]

After selecting dates:

[image]

The form itself is displayed by embedding a third party JavaScript link on the page - is there anything I can do to prevent this from happening? I can't figure it out!

Note: The page uses a YouTube video background which is blocked by the firewall where I am working from at the moment (hence the grey background), but is not causing any JavaScript errors. The problem is the same on all mobiles and on networks where the background is able to load.

Live example at #########.com (address will be removed when resolved)

Thanks

**UPDATE:** As per the answer from Wouter, removing the `overflow: hidden` from `<section class="gg-section hero video-home" id="dots-section1">` fixes the issue, but unfortunately that causes other layout problems so cannot be applied.

Comment: Can you give a link at least? So that someone can find out what's wrong.

Comment: @ihpar There is a link in the question already :)

Comment: sorry my bad... Checking it right now

Comment: @Lyall It's funny. When I select a new date, it shifts to the left, but when I uncheck and check again `right:0` on the `video-background`, that doesn't happen anymore. Even when selecting new dates.

Comment: @Lyall after picking new date disabling and enabling back `right: 0` rule of `video-background` class fixes the problem. But I am not sure what causes this issue in first place... Or disabling and enabling this rule `@media (max-aspect-ratio: 16/9)
style.css?ver=4.7.5:9919
.video-foreground {
    width: 300%;
    left: -100%;
}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is likely to be caused by the video being 300% width. Try to set a overflow: hidden; to the following element:

```
<div class="video-background">
```

Comment: Thanks, that does fix the issue but unfortunately causes other layout issues on mobile (such as the preloading screen not showing correctly and the sections overlap)

Comment: https://s27.postimg.org/tfklra7pv/Screenshot_2017-08-11-12-25-56.jpg
https://s27.postimg.org/bqsuznvyr/Screenshot_2017-08-11-12-31-22.jpg

Comment: I believe the problem is being caused by the video being 300% width. In my desktop browser there was already an overlapping issue before i changed any css so it's hard for me to debug. What happens if you add an additional overflow: hidden; to the video-background class?

Comment: That seems to have fixed it! Didn't remove the overflow:hidden from your first suggestion but adding the additional one to the video-background class has worked, thanks. If you want to update your answer I'll mark it as accepted.

Comment: Yes, sorry I meant to keep both overflows. Anyway, I'm glad that worked! :) I also updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

May not help but..

I had a similar issue with page jumping and forms before.

It was caused by an `<input class="hiddencheckbox" type="checkbox" />`.

Every time I used `js` select/deselect the checkbox, the browser would try and jump to the checkbox position, which I had hidden by moving its position outside the viewport.

```
.hiddencheckbox {
    position:fixed; 
    right: -1000px; 
    // BAD WITH JS
}
```

I removed the positioning and changed it to:

```
.hiddencheckbox {
    display:none;
}
```